# How do you programmatically create a Google BigQuery schema to create a table?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, tuples

We are trying to create a table in BigQuery. We have code working from a Google example that creates the schema - but the code specifying the schema is in a tuple.

The code looks like this:

```
table.schema = (
    bigquery.SchemaField('Name', 'STRING'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('Age', 'INTEGER'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('Weight', 'FLOAT'),
)
```

The problem we face is that we have the header fields we need in a list (i.e. [“Name”, “Age”, “Weight”]) - but as we understand it - tuples are immutable.

As a result, we are unable to do code like this because it throws an immutable object error:

```
 for field in field_list:
   table.schema.append(field, ‘STRING’)
```

How do we create the table schema from a list of headers when the tuple structure is immutable? How do we create all the fields in the object?

Comment: Is there a reason not to execute a DDL statement as a query instead? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_table_statement

Comment: What do you mean by the header fields are in a list? Do you have an example?

Comment: @WillianFuks Updated the question with the example list.

Comment: Can you show what you tried so far?

Comment: i am not sure what exactly the problem :o( can you elaborate please?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard Do DDL commands work from the Python BigQuery library? (https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/usage/tables.html) We don't seem to be able to get the CREATE command to work that way.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying. You need to run a query, as you would a SELECT statement, but pass the CREATE TABLE statement instead.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard We found the problem. Authentication was failing silently. Changing the code to this worked to create tables for us: client=bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(service_account_file_path)
sql="CREATE TABLE temp.temp (user STRING)"
client.query(sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new Python BigQuery API changed from a tuple to a list which means you can now programmatically do what you is asked with code like this:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud.bigquery.client import Client
service_account_file_path = "/auth/key.json" # your service account auth file file
client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(service_account_file_path)

schema = []
for field_name in field_name_list:
    schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField(field_name, "STRING", mode="REQUIRED"))

table_id = "your_project_id.your_dataset_name.your_table_name"
table = bigquery.Table(table_id, schema=schema)
table = client.create_table(table)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need this:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
headers = [
   ('Name', 'STRING'), 
   ('Age', 'INTEGER'), 
   ('Weight', 'STRING'),
   ('any_thing_else', 'STRING'), ...
]
schema = map(lambda n: bigquery.SchemaField(*n), headers)
table.schema = tuple(schema)
```

Comment: We tried it. That gave us a type error: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-669bbce8abdd> in <module>
     81 ]
     82 schema = map(lambda n: bigquery.SchemaField(*n), headers)
---> 83 table.schema = tuple(schema)